# How to see the data in SQLite database browser?

Tags: android, sqlite

The code given below is written for entering values in the database.
But this code prints data values in the logcat window.
I need to see the data values in SQLite database browser.
I know how to see it.
But I don't find my app package name in DDMS->File explorer tab->data->data->(here I do not find my package).
I want to know how to see these data values in SQLite database browser and what other modification do I need to do in my code to view data in SQLite database browser, not in logcat.

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

}
```

Here is contact class

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

public class Contact {

//private variables
int _id;
String _name;
String _phone_number;

// Empty constructor
public Contact(){

}
// constructor
public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}

// constructor
public Contact(String name, String _phone_number){
    this._name = name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting name
public String getName(){
    return this._name;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name){
    this._name = name;
}

// getting phone number
public String getPhoneNumber(){
    return this._phone_number;
}

// setting phone number
public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
    this._phone_number = phone_number;
}
}
```

This is main activity class named AndroidSQlite tutorial activity.java

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // Inserting Contacts
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Srinivas", "9199999999"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy", "9522222222"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik", "9533333333"));

    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
            // Writing Contacts to log
    Log.d("Name: ", log);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: R u using emulator and real device?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the sqlite database browser 2.0 from following link, it is easy to use..I am using this. You can track all the things which are happening in database.
by using this, you can do all the tasks relates with the sqlite database,
[Get SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/)

I hope it will be useful for you....!!!

Answer (score 0):

By default sqlite database is created in the application's packagename. You can not view this location if you are executing your code in real device.

If you want to view your sqlite database then save the database to sd card using below syntax.

```
File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/mydb/mydatabase.db" ); 
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
System.out.println("Its open? "  + db.isOpen());
```

Once these lines get execute your database is created under the `mydb` folder. Just attach your device using USB cable and copy & paste sqlite file to pc and view it in the pc using sqliteviewer program.

Comment: I am not using real device, I am using Emulator and I am looking for my package name DDMS perspective in eclipse

Comment: There is a plugin for Eclipse called SQLite Manager (from Questoid), so you can browse the db from the DDMS perspective

Comment: How to install this plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If your comfortable using SQL statements to look into the DB/tables you can also use adb commands to do so.

```
adb -e shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/your.app.package/databases/yourdb.name
```

On the sqlite prompt you can use any SQL commands to view and manipulate your DB.